# Join in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /User/

        db_MVCEntities context = new db_MVCEntities();
        public ActionResult Index(tblLogin log)
        {
            var login = from o in context.tblLogins 
                     join od in context.tblReaders 
                     on o.ReaderId equals od.ReaderId 
                     where o.Username=="user"
                     select new { od.ReaderName};

            if (login != null) 
            {
                Session["uname"] = login.ToString();
                return View(context.tblBookInfoes.ToList());
            }
            return View("Index");
        }
```

I'm trying to join 2 tables tblLogin and tblReader. dB_MVCEntities is my entity and it contains tblLogins and tblReaders rly. Here I have to take the name of the reader from tblReader where username is given in the tblLogin table using join. 
But its not working :(
The output seems like

```
SELECT [Extent1].[ReaderId] AS [ReaderId], 
       [Extent2].[ReaderName] AS [ReaderName] 
FROM [dbo].[tblLogin] AS [Extent1] 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblReader] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ReaderId] = [Extent2].[ReaderId] 
WHERE 'user' = [Extent1].[Username]
```

Please help

Comment: This is a linq-2-sql / EF question rather than MVC. Can you confirm - tblReader has many tblLogin, and tblLogin has 1 tblReader?

Comment: I'm using ADO.NET entity datamodel to generate the model classes in MVC. tblReader and tblLogin are my tables and tblReaders and tblLogins are the classes generated by the entity framework